# do not view attachment is cell D2 is not marked

Tags: excel, vba

The VB below only sends an attachment if cell D2 is marked with an "x".  I can not seem to figure out how not to load or view the attachment if C2 is marked with an "x".  Currently the VB runs and if C2 is marked with an "x" the user sees the attachment but it is not added to the email, is it possible to prevent the attachment from being viewed/opened?  Thank you :).

**VB**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim WS As Worksheet, Rng As Range, c As Range
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
Dim Msg As String, Addr As String, FName As String, i As Long
Dim obj As Object
Dim MyFile As String, MyFileCopy As String

'define path
MyFileCopy = "L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form Attachment.xlsx"

'create a separate sheet2 to mail out
Sheets(2).Copy
Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
With wkb
    .SaveAs MyFileCopy
    .Close True
End With

' create connection, check condition, send email
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")
Set Rng = WS.Range("A2", WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

 For Each c In Rng

        Msg = "For " & c.Offset(, 1) & Chr(14) & Chr(14)
        For i = 3 To 14
            If LCase(WS.Cells(c.Row, i)) = "x" Then
                Msg = Msg & "   -" & WS.Cells(1, i) & Chr(14)
            End If
        Next

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = c.Offset(, 0)
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Daily Operational Safety Briefing"
            .Body = Msg
            If LCase(c.Offset(, 3)) = "x" Then .Attachments.Add MyFileCopy, 1
            .Send
        End With

Next c

'confirm message sent and delete copy
MsgBox "The data has been emailed sucessfully.", vbInformation
Kill MyFileCopy

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

' Exit and do not save
Application.Quit
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not 100% clear on what you are asking: do you want to the macro to look at column C instead of column D to decide whether or not include the attachment? or in addition to column D? what does this mean * is it possible to prevent the attachment from being viewed/opened?*

Comment: I am going to mark this as solved as I do not think this is worth trying to fix.     The VB works as is except for one thing which I will post.  Thank you :).

Comment: changing the title to have `[SOLVED]` will not do anything to mark it solved. Having an answer that is given marked as the correct answer is the only way to solve it. If you end up posting your own answer, you can mark that. Otherwise, others will never know the solution. Lastly, I think it can be an easy fix, once I fully understand what you want.

Comment: Change `If LCase(c.Offset(, 3)) = "x"` to `If LCase(c.Offset(, 2)) = "x"`...